# added cylinder looks like it's the wrong size

Tags: mesh, dimensions

During mesh edit, I'm trying to add a cylinder that has a 0.125" radius.  Seems straightforward enough.  But I'm finding that the dimensions look completely wrong.  See screenshots of 0.5", 0.25", and 0.125" radius cylinders below (viewed on-end).  The grid pattern is 1" squares.

the size doesn't look right.  What is going on here.  If I draw a line approx 1/8 of the distance from the center of the cylinder to the first line, I would expect it to be near the size of the 3D cursor.  But it's much bigger.  What is going on here, how do I fix this?

I'm setting the size in the "add cylinder" dialog.  It reads, for example, "0' 125 thou"

The view is directly down the Z axis, with an orthographic projection.

[image: 0.5 inch radius]

[image: 0.25" radius]

[image: 0.125" radius]

UPDATE:  Added units settings screenshots

[image: Scene Units settings]

[image: layout text info display, showing grid lines are inches]

Blender v2.91.2, Windows 10, fresh install

Comment: What is your unit scale set to in the scene properties?

Comment: @Psyonicl:  I updated the question with screenshots to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by a "solidify" modifier that I had on the object I was editing.  Applying the modifier or deleting it before adding the cylinder solved the problem.